# Playing RTSP Video stream with authentication Android

Tags: android, video-streaming, rtsp

I have Server that streams MPEG-4 H264 decoded video via RTSP with simple authentication.
How can I provide authentication details to MediaPlayer ?

Answer (score 2):

You can set your headers manually when using [`setDataSource (Context context, Uri uri, Map<String, String> headers)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource%28android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri,%20java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%3E%29). I'd guess (never worked with RTSP, yet) that you need an `"Authorization"` header with a [base64-encoded username and password combination](http://thompsonng.blogspot.de/2011/01/rtsp-basic-authentication.html).

Comment: Looks like exactly what I need. Unfortunately my camera is dead , and I can't test it right now. But I will sure accept your answer if it will work.Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, headers only works for HTTP and HTTPS, currently no love for RTSP.